# PyQt Window Closing Closes the Entire Application

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have some strange trouble with `PyQt5` application creating. Closing the window kills the whole application, though I don't need it, because I also have a tray icon. I am running python3 on Debian, though I don't think it matters.

There is a solution for C#. [Close a windows form without exiting the entire application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599097/close-a-windows-form-without-exiting-the-entire-application) 
Creating another form, but not displaying it. Is it OK for `PyQt`?

```
import sys

import PyQt5.QtWidgets

class SettingsMenu(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Settings")
        self.resize(300, 200)

class ContextMenu(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QMenu):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.settings_action = self.addAction('Settings')
       self.settings_action.triggered.connect(self.display_settings_menu)

    def display_settings_menu(self, event):
        self.settings_menu = SettingsMenu()
        self.settings_menu.show()

class TrayIcon(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setIcon(PyQt5.QtGui.QIcon('icon.xpm'))
        self.setContextMenu(ContextMenu())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tray_icon = TrayIcon()
    tray_icon.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
```

solved my problem. It seems that PyQt5 counts only opened and displayed windows, and TrayIcon does not count as one of them.

Comment: This solved my problem. Closing any new window, including selecting a file in QFileDialog, was quickly making my app exit (exit normally I must add). Your answer solved my problem, thanks a million!